# What does perl special variable $-[0] and $+[0] means

Tags: perl, predefined-variables, special-variables

I want to know the meaning of perl special variables `$-[0]` and `$+[0]`

I have googled and found that `$-` represent number of lines left on the page and `$+` represent the last bracket matched by the last search pattern.

But my question is what `$-[0]` and `$+[0]` means in context of regular expressions.

Let me know if code sample is required.

Comment: Did you read the perlvar perldoc? http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html  The example on `$+[0]` is quite clear.

Comment: You should be more familiarize with [manual][1].

Comment: The variables you're looking for are `@-` and `@+`.

Comment: i don't know why everyone act so harsh and downvote when i ask noob questions...i have just started working on perl and obviously i was not familiar with @-..i have been given task of reading some existing code and there was no @- so how would I know about it..I have spend an hour searching for $-[0] and playing with the code to understand it myself before asking this question....is stackoverflow not for noobs?

Comment: @raina77ow i searched the manual but as I mentioned I was searching for $-[0] so it gave no matching results....anyway I got your point

Comment: +1 for noob support. I remember the first time I saw $_[0] in a subroutine.  Had me scratching my head a bit.

Comment: @BillRuppert thanks for the support...but I get the point of downvoters...In future I will do a more in-depth search on official perldoc before asking any question...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [`perldoc perlvar`](http://metacpan.org/module/perlvar) about `@+` and `@-`.

> `$+[0]` is the offset into the string of the end of the entire match.
>
> `$-[0]` is the offset of the start of the last successful match.

Answer (score 8):

These are both elements from an array (indicated by the square brackets and number), so you want to search for @- (the array) and not $- (an unrelated scalar variable).

The commend

```
perldoc perlvar
```

explains Perl's special variables. If you search in there for @- you will find.

`$-[0] is the offset of the start of the last successful match. $-[n] is the offset of the start of the substring matched by n-th subpattern, or undef if the subpattern did not match`.

Answer (score 6):

Adding example for better understanding of `$-[0]`,`$+[0]`

Also adding info on variable `$+`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str="This is a Hello World program";
$str=~/Hello/;

local $\="\n"; # Used to separate output 

print $-[0]; # $-[0] is the offset of the start of the last successful match. 

print $+[0]; # $+[0] is the offset into the string of the end of the entire match. 

$str=~/(This)(.*?)Hello(.*?)program/;

print $str;

print $+;                    # This returns the last bracket result match
```

Output:

```
D:\perlex>perl perlvar.pl
10                           # position of 'H' in str
15                           # position where match ends in str
This is a Hello World program
 World
```

Comment: thanks for the nice example..the concept of @+ @- $- $+ are completely clear to me now...but this will definitely help future visitors +1